# C# Best practice - Counting how many times each date occurs

Tags: c#, list, datetime, dictionary

I'm looking for a best practice for counting how many times each date occurs in a list.

For now, I have working code (just tested) but I think the way I did is not so good.

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();
//Fill list here

var dateCounter = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

foreach (var dateTime in dates)
{
   if (dateCounter.ContainsKey(dateTime))
   {
      //Increase count
      dateCounter[dateTime] = dateCounter[dateTime] + 1;
   }
   else
   {
      //Add to dictionary
      dateCounter.Add(dateTime, 1);
   }
}
```

Anyone who knows a better solution?

Comment: FYI: The main issue I'd have with this is for each repeated date, you look up into the list 3 times (`Contains` and each `dateCounter[dateTime]`). It can be done with just one lookup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dates.GroupBy(d => d).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: I wish I could type quicker :)

Comment: Thanks, taking this as an answer in 8 minutes ;)

Comment: I was typing the same solution when I saw "an answer has been made to this.." You typed/answered quicker than me this time.